# Save modified WordprocessingDocument to new file

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk, office-2007

I'm attempting to open a Word document, change some text and then save the changes to a new document. I can get the first bit done using the code below but I can't figure out how to save the changes to a NEW document (specifying the path and file name).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using System.IO;

namespace WordTest
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string template = @"c:\data\hello.docx";
        string documentText;

        using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(template, true))
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream()))
            {
                documentText = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }


            documentText = documentText.Replace("##Name##", "Paul");
            documentText = documentText.Replace("##Make##", "Samsung");

            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create)))
            {
                writer.Write(documentText);
            }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

I'm a complete beginner at this, so forgive the basic question!

Comment: For those that get to this through Google and see we're basically just following this:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-search-and-replace-text-in-a-document-part  EXCEPT we're trying to save it in a new document, not the original one.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

If you use a `MemoryStream` you can save the changes to a new file like this:

```
byte[] byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes("c:\\data\\hello.docx");
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    stream.Write(byteArray, 0, (int)byteArray.Length);
    using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(stream, true))
    {
       // Do work here
    }
    // Save the file with the new name
    File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\data\\newFileName.docx", stream.ToArray()); 
}
```

Comment: Good adaptation of what is at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-12//ee945362(v=office.12) .  Can also do `using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("C:\\data\\newFileName.docx", System.IO.FileMode.CreateNew)) { stream.WriteTo(fileStream); }` instead of `File.WriteAllBytes( ... )` If desiring to just get the bytes, can do `byteArray = stream.ToArray();` after the "wordDoc" `using` block is closed, in the middle.

Comment: If this solution is not working for you just write the following line at the end of "// Do work here": wordDoc.Close(); >> This command is what actually writes everything to the stream.

Answer (score 18):

In Open XML SDK 2.5:

```
    File.Copy(originalFilePath, modifiedFilePath);

    using (var wordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(modifiedFilePath, isEditable: true))
    {
        // Do changes here...
    }
```

`wordprocessingDocument.AutoSave` is true by default so Close and Dispose will save changes.
`wordprocessingDocument.Close` is not needed explicitly because the using block will call it.

This approach doesn't require entire file content to be loaded into memory like in accepted answer. It isn't a problem for small files, but in my case I have to process more docx files with embedded xlsx and pdf content at the same time so the memory usage would be quite high.

Answer (score 5):

Simply copy the source file to the destination and make changes from there.

```
File.copy(source,destination);
using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(destination, true))
    {
       \\Make changes to the document and save it.
       wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
       wordDoc.Close();
    }
```

Hope this works.

Comment: 1. It looks like you wanted to write `wordDoc.Save()`.
2. There is no `Save()` method. So this doesn't seem like a valid solution to me.

Is there anything I'm missing??

Comment: Note that this code `MainDocumentPart.Document.Save()` won't save the whole package / word document. There are other parts that need to be saved too (my issue was that the footnotes weren't saving, which aren't under the `MainDocumentPart`). I ended up using the accepted answer rather than trying to work out what bits i needed to call save on.

Comment: For those you have save individually.

Comment: In Open XML SDK 2.5 Save doesn't have to be called explicitly, Close and Dispose will save if WordprocessingDocument.AutoSave is true. Close doesn't have to called explicitly either because the using block will call Dispose what in turn will call Close.

Answer (score 3):

This approach allows you to buffer the "template" file without batching the whole thing into a `byte[]`, perhaps allowing it to be less resource intensive.

```
var templatePath = @"c:\data\hello.docx";
var documentPath = @"c:\data\newFilename.docx";

using (var template = File.OpenRead(templatePath))
using (var documentStream = File.Open(documentPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
    template.CopyTo(documentStream);

    using (var document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(documentStream, true))
    {
        //do your work here

        document.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

For me [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb508261.aspx) worked fine:

```
// To search and replace content in a document part.
public static void SearchAndReplace(string document)
{
    using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(document, true))
    {
        string docText = null;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream()))
        {
            docText = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

        Regex regexText = new Regex("Hello world!");
        docText = regexText.Replace(docText, "Hi Everyone!");

        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create)))
        {
            sw.Write(docText);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That saves it to the SAME document and therefore does not answer the question.