# Fill word template data using openXML SDK

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml-sdk, word-contentcontrol

I have an word file template and xml file for data. I want to find content Content control in word and get data from xml and then replace text in word template. i'm using the following code but it is not updating word file.

```
using (WordprocessingDocument document = WordprocessingDocument.CreateFromTemplate(txtWordFile.Text))       
{
           MainDocumentPart mainPart = document.MainDocumentPart;
            IEnumerable<SdtBlock> block = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtBlock>().Where
                (r => r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val == "TotalClose");
            Text t = block.Descendants<Text>().Single();
             t.Text = "13,450,542";
            mainPart.Document.Save();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should write changes to temporary file.
See [Save modified WordprocessingDocument to new file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818160/save-modified-wordprocessingdocument-to-new-file) or my code from work project:

```
    MemoryStream yourDocStream = new MemoryStream();
    ... // populate yourDocStream with .docx bytes
    using (Package package = Package.Open(yourDocStream, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
    {
        //  Load the document XML in the part into an XDocument instance.  
        PackagePart packagePart = LoadXmlPackagePart(package);
        XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Load(XmlReader.Create(packagePart.GetStream()));

        // making changes

        //  Save the XML into the package  
        using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(packagePart.GetStream(FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)))
        {
            xDocument.Save(xw);
        }

        var resultDocumentBytes = yourDocStream.ToArray();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

For anyone still struggling with this - you can check out this library https://github.com/antonmihaylov/OpenXmlTemplates

With it you can replace the text inside all content controls of the document based on a JSON object (or a basic C# dictionary) without writing specific code, instead you specify the variable name in the tag of the content control.

(Note - i am the maker of that library, but it is open sourced and licensed under LGPLv3)

Answer (score 0):

The basic approach you use works fine, but I'm surprised you're not getting any compile-time errors because

```
IEnumerable<SdtBlock> block = mainPart.Document
                                      .Body
                                      .Descendants<SdtBlock>()
                                      .Where(r => r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val == "TotalClose");
```

is not compatible with

```
Text t = block.Descendants<Text>().Single();
```

`block`, as `IEnumerable` has no `Descendants` property. You either need to loop through all the items in `IEnumerable` and perform this on each item, or you need to define and instantiate a single item, like this:

```
using (WordprocessingDocument document = WordprocessingDocument.CreateFromTemplate(txtWordFile.Text))
{
    MainDocumentPart mainPart = pkgDoc.MainDocumentPart;

    SdtBlock block = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtBlock>().Where
            (r => r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val == "test1").FirstOrDefault();

    Text t = block.Descendants<Text>().Single();
    t.Text = "13,450,542";

    mainPart.Document.Save();
}
```