# Edit and Save DOCX Using Powershell

Tags: powershell, openxml, docx

I have slightly modified [this PowerShell script](https://hinchley.net/articles/read-a-microsoft-excel-workbook-using-powershell-and-the-open-xml-sdk/) for my work with DOCX files but would like to edit the DOCX file in place.

After running the script, the terminal displays the error message: "You cannot call a method on a null-value expression" in reference to line 43, `$document.Save()`.

I am not sure the reason for the error as the path to `$document` is already defined earlier in the script. What am I missing?

Here is the whole script:

```bsh
    Param ([string]$path = $(throw "-path is required."))

    Import-Module "C:\scripts\PSGenericMethods.psm1"
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Program Files (x86)\Open XML SDK\V2.5\lib\DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll") | out-null

    [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("DocumentFormat.OpenXml") | out-null
    [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging") | out-null
    [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing") | out-null
    [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("OpenXmlPowerTools") | out-null

    [DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.WordprocessingDocument]$document = $null
    $document = [DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.WordprocessingDocument]::Open($path, $true)

    [DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.MainDocumentPart]$MainDocumentPart = $document.MainDocumentPart

    [DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Document]$InnerDocument = $document.Document

    [DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Body]$Body = $document.Body

    [DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Paragraph]$paragraph = $document.Paragraph

    [DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.ParagraphMarkRunProperties]$ParagraphMarkRunProperties = $document.ParagraphMarkRunProperties

    [DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.ParagraphProperties]$ParagraphProperties = $document.ParagraphProperties

    [DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.ParagraphStyleId]$ParagraphStyleId = $document.ParagraphStyleId

    [DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Run]$run = $document.Run

    $paragraphs = Invoke-GenericMethod -InputObject $MainDocumentPart.Document -MethodName Descendants -GenericType DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Paragraph

    $runs = Invoke-GenericMethod -InputObject $MainDocumentPart.Document -MethodName Descendants -GenericType DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Run

    foreach ($run in $runs) { 
     if ($run.RunProperties.Languages.Val) {

    <#[String]$value = $run.InnerText#>
    [String]$language = $run.RunProperties.Languages.Val

    '{{$span xml:lang="{0}"$}}{1}{{$/span}}$' -f $language, $run.InnerText
    }
    }
    $document.close()
```

**Update:**
After modifying the script, I now no longer have the problem with "You cannot call a method on a null value expression" error. The problem is that I am not sure how to save results to the file.

This may be a duplicate of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818160/save-modified-wordprocessingdocument-to-new-file).

Can anyone suggest a method for saving the changes to the file?

Answer (score 1):

Variable names in PowerShell are NOT case-sensitive. You destroy your "document" with this line I think:

```
[DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Document]$Document = $document.Document
```

Because `$Document` is the same variable as `$document`.

Comment: most likely this is correct, if not, just add a breakpoint in `[DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.WordprocessingDocument]$document = $null` and follow the value of document from then on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211084/discussion-between-joseph-polizzotto-and-thomas).